# The value attribute of a lightning-input-field that is a text area returns an odd value

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

In LWC, I usually handle the value of a field like so:

.html:

```
 <lightning-input-field
                    field-name="Footballer_Name__c"
                    onchange={handleFootballerName}
                    required
                    value={footballerNameValue}
                  >
</lightning-input-field>
```

.js

```
handleFootballerName(event) {
    this.footballerName = event.target.value;
    this.formObject[event.currentTarget.fieldName] = event.target.value;
  }

 footballerNameValue() {
    return this.footballerName 
  }
```

However, I have noticed that when Footballer_Name__c is a text area or long text area, the field in the LWC is pre-populated with the contents of the method name:

```
footballerNameValue(){return console.log("footballer name is is " +JSON.stringify(this.footballerName)),this.footballerName}
```

I do not get this behavior for other field types.

Is there a specific way in which one needs to handle the value attribute for Lightning text fields?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using `event.detail.value`, not `event.target.value`

This is because you are outside the shadow DOM boundary for that component, and only the `detail` parameter of the event can propagate through.

Comment: Agreed! This was a typo too!

Answer (score 0):

I have realised a typo - I was omitting the get.

So it should be:

```
  get footballerNameValue() {
        return this.footballerName 
      }
```

Ouch!